# What is the best PhD choice for gauge-gravity duality research?

Tags: phd, mathematics, physics

I am a mathematician but want to do a PhD in mathematical physics focusing on gauge-gravity duality and more generally quantum gravity, what is the most appropriate PhD choice to do research in this field, is it an astrophysics (cosmology) PhD or a particle physics one?

I am looking for a program that I can take a lot of relevant abstract mathematics courses like topological quantum field theory, functorial quantum field theory, algebraic geometry and topology, while at the same time I can get a good understanding of physics concepts about quantum gravity.

Comment: I'm hoping this won't be treated as a "shopping question" since it asks about a _type_ of degree, not recommendations for institutions and such.

Comment: @Buffy the problem is that many physics departments won't distinguish between astrophysics, cosmology or particle physics. There will be separate research groups for these topics but not separate departments. This is country-dependent, but in the US (where I suspect OP is), aren't admissions are generally handled at departmental level rather than group level?

Comment: @lost-mid you may want to search for particle cosmology PhDs, as these are going to cover the topics you're interested in.

Comment: @astronat, yes, in the US, admissions is usually a department level matter, not individual professors. Students entering with only a BS will have a lot of time to look around and choose both a specialty and an advisor. It is a bit tighter for an MS entrant unless they want to spend a lot of time.

Comment: So, is this for US admissions? And, if so, do you already have a MS?

Comment: I am considering US admission, I am finishing my m.sc this year.

Answer (score 4):

At least in the US, your first question should be whether to do a mathematics or a physics PhD.  It's possible to work as a physicist with a mathematics PhD and vice versa (and I know people who do it), but it's hard enough to find an academic job (which is the only kind of job that will pay you for theoretical research of the kind you seem to be interested in) as it is, and having background and teaching experience in the "wrong" field makes it much harder.

It's important to understand that physics and mathematics are different fields with different ideas of what it means for a statement to be true.  In mathematics, a statement is true if and only if someone has given a valid mathematical proof for it.  In physics - well I'm a mathematician who is ignorant of physics, so I think it's best to let physicists speak for themselves - but it's not what I just wrote for mathematics.  Their *definition* (in the mathematical sense of definition) of truth is different.  Which definition of truth do you want to work with?

Also important - would you rather teach introductory physics or calculus?

In either case, you want to be at a university where the mathematics and physics departments have a good relationship with each other.  (For this purpose unlike many others, having no relationship does not count as having a good relationship.)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting good general answers from qualified users with broad knowledge, which would be useful if you were deciding between physics and math in general. But your question is a lot more specific than that, and deserves a specific answer.

In the US, you don't apply to a subfield like "particle physics". You either get a math PhD or a physics PhD. In addition, while you might be required to take some basic courses, there is typically little restriction on what advanced courses you're allowed to take. However, topics such as gauge-gravity duality and quantum gravity are studied almost exclusively in the physics department, under the name of "high energy theory". If you're sure you want to study this, you need to apply for a physics PhD.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for US admissions, then you don't really need to choose a specialty to be admitted in most fields. You can join a larger physics program that has a lot of professors likely to have a lot of interests.

This is especially true (US only, perhaps) if you enter with only a BS degree, since there is expected advanced coursework normally required before you need to choose a specialty or an advisor. It is also fairly common in US to change fields, within reason, after a BS. I think that math to physics would normally be possible. Especially mathematical physics of various flavors.

State Universities are usually classified R1 and tend to have large faculties so you have some choices.

Moreover, if you get "close enough" in your doctoral studies, then you can further specialize afterwards. Your degree doesn't need to define you forever, though it takes some work (and luck).